# Multiple folders within $Recycle.Bin

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I'm cleaning up a friend's Windows 7 SP1 computer and making sure everything is in order.

The `$Recycle.Bin` folder in the root of `C:`, has not one, but *two*, folders inside.  The names of those folders are identical, except for the digits after the last dash.

He only has one user account on the system (plus the Admin account).

I'm guessing that perhaps one of the folders is the recycle bin for his user account, and the other is the recycle bin for the Admin account.

Is this guess accurate, or is there a more accurate explanation?

Comment: that is correct a raw view of what goes on in the recycle bin, big ID numbers, for seperate users.  I have deleted it all before , doing it with high permission, shift deleting so it doesnt loop back in on itself. So far it always re-creates what is needed, So i assume (only) that it doesnt blow anything up.

Comment: @Psycogeek Thanks.  So there will always be at least two folders in there: one for a user account, and one for the admin account?

Comment: correct.  If your only admin ever, just 1.

Answer (score 2):

The part of the folder-name that is identical for both folders is the
SID (Security Identifier),
used in general by Windows to uniquely identify an object like
a user or a group.

In this case, it identifies the Domain or Local Computer Identifier
(or one or more sub-authority values) of the
computer (or network) which created the folder.

You can use the free [SidToName](http://joeware.net/freetools/tools/sidtoname/index.htm) batch utility to convert this string
to a name, or find it yourself in the registry under the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
as the last part of the path inside the ProfileImagePath item.

The "500" or "1000" at the end is known as the Relative ID (RID).
"500" means that the user is the built-in system Administrator.
A user or group that 
was not created by default will have a Relative ID of 1000 and higher.

The two folders found in the bin are therefore that of the Administrator
and the logged-on user, marked as created by the local computer by having its
SID as their prefix.

References :

- [$Recycle.Bin Forensics for Windows 7 and Windows Vista](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/FYS102D/Recycle.Bin.Forensics.for.Windows7.and.Windows.Vista.pdf)
- [Wikipedia - Security Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)
- [Wikipedia - Relative ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_ID)

Answer (score 1):

As @Psycogeek says, that view is indeed a raw view of the Recycle Bin. Those ID numbers are pointers to Windows. If the ID in the registry matches, Windows knows that that folder is indeed assigned to said user.

If you are the only user, I would assume that you are able to delete both without anything major happening.